# sorting date with time in descending order in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, datetime

I have dynamic date and time being generated and I need to sort them in descending order using JavaScript.

my data is in the below format.

```
var array= ["25-Jul-2017 12:46:39 pm","25-Jul-2017 12:52:23 pm","25-Jul-2017 12:47:18 pm"];
```

Anyone help would be appreciated.

Comment: `array.sort((a,b) => new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Comment: @Rajesh - that's not cross browser friendly

Comment: Do you mean `-`? We can use ternary operator with `a > b ? 1 : a < b : -1 : 0`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working code for you:

```js
var array = ["25-Jul-2017 12:46:39 pm", "25-Jul-2017 12:52:23 pm", "25-Jul-2017 12:47:18 pm", "25-Jul-2017 12:59:18 pm"];

array.sort((a, b) => new Date(b).getTime() - new Date(a).getTime())

console.log(array)
```

Comment: that wont work in firefox - you're a chrome user, right?

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that. Yes, I did that in chrome.

Comment: Whoops. Yes @Rajesh. I think, while I was coding in the code-editor, you had already commented. Its a common sorting code.

Comment: @JaromandaX - Do you have know how we can make it work across browsers? what's the fix?

Comment: use a library like moment.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = ["25-Jul-2017 12:46:39 pm", "25-Jul-2017 12:52:23 pm", "25-Jul-2017 12:47:18 pm"];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(b) - new Date(a);
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: First its missing explanation. Second, please check other answer. Its already covered

Comment: Agree with @Rajesh. It's covered. Secondly, start using code editor so that people can see the output. And lastly, yes, you need to add some explanation about your answer.

Comment: Adding to @MilanChheda comment, `<>` icon is used to launch code editor. You can put your *CSS/HTML/JS* code and make it executable. This helps people to verify you code.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var array= ["25-Jul-2017 12:46:39 pm","25-Jul-2017 12:52:23 pm","25-Jul-2017 12:47:18 pm"];
var dateAr = [];

for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
 dateAr.push(new Date(array[i].replace(/-/g,'/')).getTime()); //convert to milisecond
}


var sortAr = dateAr.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  }); //sort it

var resArr = [];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
 resArr.push(new Date(sortAr[i])); //make date object
}
console.log(resArr);
```

Convert to millisecond from Date , and then sort it. and make Date object from millisecond. use this `replace(/-/g,'/')` to replace date string, it works in all browser.